# How to enable rdp service on manjaro?

Tags: remote-desktop, archlinux, rdp, manjaro

I need login to manjaro from windows.

I found that on ubuntu or else xrdp is used, but not found on manjaro. `sudo pacman -S xrdp` wont work.

Answer (score 2):

xrdp is in aur: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xrdp/

You could run for example `yay -S xrdp`

Answer (score 0):

you can install remmina from snap store, no need to aur

```
sudo snap install remmina
```

Remmina supports multiple network protocols in an integrated and consistent user interface. and currently RDP, VNC, SPICE, NX, XDMCP, SSH and WWW are supported.

here is the link to snap store : [snapstore/remmina](https://snapcraft.io/remmina)